# Problem with a validation rule in Order Item

Tags: validation-rule, product, orderitem

Hey everyone I'm kind of a newbie in my journey in salesforce. And I'm kind of struggling with this one validation rule I'm trying to write.

Now the thing is in Order Item there is the product code and in the product code there are only two type of codes. Codes that start with ABC and GYH(ABC.1404.4323 or GYH.134.5343) and the numbers change according to the product.

The issue is I don't want the sales rep to be able to add two different products in the add products section. So if the sales rep chooses a product that starts with ABC as the product code, he/she can't add a product that starts with GYH product code and vice versa.

I've tried nested If statements such as the one below;

```
IF(
    CONTAINS(PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode, "GYH"),
    false,
    IF(
        CONTAINS(PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode, "ABC"),
        true,
        false
    )
)
```

even though it works when both of them are added, when only a product with "ABC" code is entered it shows the error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validation rule isn't the right tool for this job.

Validation rules can only look at a single record at a time. You can include data from *parent* records (i.e. you could reference data on the `Order` in a formula on `OrderLineItem`), but you can't reference *child* records, nor *sibling* records (i.e. other `OrderLineItem`s in a formula on `OrderLineItem`).

The most natural feature that you could use here is likely *pricebooks* ([relevant documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.products_pricebooks.htm&type=5)). The general idea is

- You'd have two custom pricebooks
- One to contain only `ABC` code products, the other only `GYH` products
- When creating an `Order`, your sales team would need to select one of those pricebooks, and they'd only be able to add line items for products from that particular pricebook (i.e. only products with one of the two product code patterns)

The other option would be to create a *Flow* (more specifically, a record-triggered flow), or a *Trigger*. Flows are more administrative/point-and-click, and Triggers involve writing code (using Salesforce's proprietary, Java-like language, Apex) and tests.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and coming up with various recommendations. In the end, we decided to separate the price books according to the product code and this solved our problem.